# line break (\n or br)using string-array item ignored by html

Tags: java, android, html, string

## SOLVED code updated

when I write a text on edit text to be searched on textview it highlights the particular text in colour but the line breaks are all gone and all my sentence appear in one sentence.And this problem appears when I click search for text to be highlighted.Else before I click search it shows all the line breaks.Please help!upvote waiting

```
// java code
 public void onClick(View v) {
//solved code here
                String textTOHighlight=etText.getText().toString();
                String originalText=textView.getText().toString();
                if(originalText.isEmpty()) return;
                String modifiedText=originalText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />").replaceAll(textTOHighlight, "<font color='red'>"+textTOHighlight+"</font>");
                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(modifiedText),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            }
```

```
// string code
<string-array name="chapters">
<item>This is \n first test<item>
<item>this is \n second test<item>
</string-array>
```

```
// activity
<EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_text"
        android:hint="Enter text"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"/>
```

//for example before i input text to search

"this is
first test"

//but after I input text to search it highlights particular text but shows without new line

"this is first test"

```
//all i did was on each button click go to specific chapter.By the way this portion has nothing to do.
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//solved code
        String text="";
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1 : {
                 text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[0].replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button1 : {
                text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[1].replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> New edit

Try a new one,

Use this as it is

```
// string code
<string-array name="chapters">
    <item>This is \n first test<item>
    <item>this is \n second test<item>
</string-array>
```

And,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String text="";
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1 : {
            text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[0].replaceAll("\n", "<br />"));
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button1 : {
            text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[1].replaceAll("\n", "<br />"));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> Try this sample code

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText edt = findViewById(R.id.edt);
        final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[0].replaceAll("\n", "<br />")), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String textTOHighlight = edt.getText().toString();
                String originalText = tv.getText().toString();

                if(originalText.isEmpty()) return;

                String modifiedText = originalText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />").replaceAll(textTOHighlight, "<font color='red'>" + textTOHighlight + "</font>");
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(modifiedText),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:hint="Enter text"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#C29090"
        android:text="Search" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:background="#474747"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
 <resources>
     <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

     <string-array name="chapters">
        <item>This is \n first test</item>
        <item>this is \n second test</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Hope it will work out :)

Comment: The problem has to be with the html when am replacing the text with highlights it ignores the new line tags.Maybe am wrong

Comment: If so,, replace <br />  instead of \n

Comment: Can you show me the code for inserting a string-array called chapters?
The question does not have that code.

Comment: Please apply it as I have just modified it.

Comment: i used your code and when i build it shows like this."This is <br /> first test".Now on search button when i click for text to search ..it shows the correct result with the line break.Now if i search again the line breaks are ignored.I hope you understood.Can you try it yourself please.Its so tricky or should i implement without html.

Comment: check below my ans for more details

Comment: Try new sample!

Comment: Now its all good except when the text is shown at first."<br />" is shown along with the text.I should convert the original text to html.Because after I search text it shows line break accordingly.

Comment: I added "Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(text);
textView.setText(htmlText); " it worked now.Your code is good but in main activity you initialised array chapters to "0" which makes all the button to point to first item else its working.

Answer (score 0):

//first output

```
This is <br /> first test
```

//Now when i enter text to search it shows correctly

```
This is
first test
```

//Now if i enter another text to search it ignores the line break again

```
This is first test
```

```
// using this solved
Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(text);
textView.setText(htmlText);
```